# How to train spacy to recognize a label without specifying the other ones?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

In order to extract the "PERSON" labels of some sentences, I'm training spacy with some sentences like "John Doe likes London and Berlin".

For this example, the training data would look like this :

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
('John Doe likes London and Berlin.', {
    'entities': [(0, 8, 'PERSON'), (15, 21, 'LOC'), (26, 32, 'LOC')]
})]
```

But I don't want to specify the other labels like London = LOC and Berlin = Loc like I did in this example.

Is it possible or do I always have to specify the other labels ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about PERSON labels then it is fine to only include training data for those.